# Where does Google Chrome store bookmarks on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, bookmarks

How can I get Google Chrome's bookmarks other than starting the browser and exporting?  I'm running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to sync your bookmarks, Google Chrome stores them in your Google Docs account. It will create a folder in your Google Docs account called "Google Chrome" with a subfolder called "Bookmarks", which will contain your bookmarks.

Comment: Comment by [guigouz](http://superuser.com/users/86149/guigouz) - "This behaviour has changed, "Chrome Sync" data appear on the google dashboard, but there's no way to access it"

Answer (score 14):

Read ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks, it's a [JSON](http://json.org/) file.

Comment: For those on OS X, it lives under "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks"

Answer (score 0):

My version of Google Chrome offered me the option to sync my bookmarks, preferences and themes to my Google account... not sure whether this is because I'm on the Beta channel though and this option may not be available to you.

It's in the "Options" | "Personal Stuff" settings menu for me.