# Where to find my Favorites in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks

Where can I find my Favorites in Google Chrome ?

Where to find the folder that contains them ?

Comment: For Linux, see: [Where does Google Chrome store bookmarks on Ubuntu?](http://superuser.com/q/158440/87805)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Windows, this is stored in the file:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks
```

On Mac OS X, this is stored in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks
```

These are JSON-formatted text files.

If you're trying to import/export bookmarks, though, you're probably better off exporting them from the user interface.  In the Wrench menu, go to Bookmarks Manager, then click Organize, then either "Import Bookmarks" or "Export Bookmarks".  This lets you import/export your bookmarks using a standard HTML file that other browsers can also import/export.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (Chromium build) this is:

```
~/.config/chromium/<profile>/Bookmarks
```

For instance:

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Bookmarks
```

It is a JSON document.

Comment: The path is ~/.config/google-chrome/<profile>/Bookmarks ("Default" default) on my machine...

Comment: @Andioid: That's because you use the Google build. If you install the free Chromium browser, the path is like what I described.

Comment: Was just pointing out the right path, since the question says "Google Chrome", not "Chromium".

Comment: @Andrioid: Just edited for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Chrome Menu Icon -> Bookmark Manager.
That's where it is

[image]

Answer (score -1):

See this

http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/search.py?ctx=en:searchbox&query=favorites

.

Comment: I'm not the one who voted you down, but this isn't very helpful--it's the equivalent of posting a link to a Google search.

Comment: Geez, I don't spoon feed people, if you want to learn about google chrome, its best to use Chromes help, its the best help there is, besides they might learn something more than the original question in the process. Teach a person to fish, don't just give them a fish to eat, thats welfare. Thanks for your support of the down vote.